# OCR replacement for MODI

Tags: .net, ocr, modi

I have recently been using the builtin OCR functionality of MODI to capture text of a window.  I use the window handle and could get text at any region or I could get the coordinates of specific text that I want to search for.

It looks like MODI has been depricated, and it isn't included in office 2010 which we're now using, so I need to find a new OCR alternative.    Are there other good libraries I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modi in office 2010. The best way is to install Modi from SharePoint Designer. Follow the link for detailed information
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760